# How to set SQL connection config on gorm v2

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I am going to gorm v2 from gorm v1. In the v1 version, I did set connection config like max connections. I did it like this but I can't set in gorm v2 and I didn't found any documentation for this. anyone can help me?

```
db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(configs.CONNECTION_STRING), &gorm.Config{})

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
        } else {
            db.DB().SetMaxOpenConns(0)
            db.DB().SetMaxIdleConns(10)
            db.DB().SetConnMaxLifetime(time.Hour)
            break
        }
```

Comment: [gorm v2 doc for connecting to the database](https://v2.gorm.io/docs/connecting_to_the_database.html)`

Answer (score 1):

You can found this answer on [this documentation](http://v2.gorm.io/docs/connecting_to_the_database.html#Connection-Pool).

however, in v2 gorm, you can change your code to this :

```
db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(configs.CONNECTION_STRING), &gorm.Config{})

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
        } else {
            dbConfig, _ := db.DB()
            dbConfig.SetMaxOpenConns(0)
            dbConfig.SetMaxIdleConns(10)
            dbConfig.SetConnMaxLifetime(time.Hour)
            break
        }
```